# Не работает бот телеграмм

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

У меня не работает код телеграмм бота на питон. Перепроверял токен и сам код. Бот просто всё игнорирует. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

```
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
bot = Bot('token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
async def photo(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "...")


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```

Comment: А на что он не реагирует?

Comment: Наверное на всё, я пишу команду /photo и он не реагирует.

Comment: Это весь код или есть еще?

Comment: Это весь код бота

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен в причине, но попробуйте так. Только свой токен вставляйте

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
async def photo(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо, большое! Не могли бы Вы объяснить, что это за второй импорт? (MemoryStorage)

Comment: Я забыл его убрать, но вообще это хранилище для стейта машины состояний FSM.

Comment: Подскажите, а какая у меня была тогда ошибка?

Comment: Скорее всего вы какой-то неправильный екзекутор или диспатчер импортировали

Answer (score 0):

```
 executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=print('Бот запущен'))
```

Замените ваш executor на приведений выше, если в терминале будет выведена запись -'Бот запущен';значит бот работает и если бот не делает то что вы хотите, то это семантическая ошибка.И Вам нужно разобраться с хендлерами...
Допустим есть такой обработчик:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
async def photo(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Какойто текст')
```

При отправке команды /photo должен отдать Вам - 'Какойто текст'